# Agoda payment not in FAQ list

Tags: payment-cards, payment

I booked a hotel through Agoda and there is no other payment option like pay now or pay later. It was just a [Book Now] button and proceeded to payment.

It shows

> Payment collected by property at any time

under my booking ID. and

> Payment for this booking has not been collected by Agoda. Payment for
>   this booking must be collected by the property

is shown in my booking voucher

Does that mean i will need to pay when i check in? or it will be deducted 2-3 days before the check in date? Anyone encounter the same before?

Answer (score 2):

From their [FAQ](https://www.agoda.com/info/agoda-faq.html?cid=-96):

> That depends on the type of booking: 1) Rate per room per night - Pay
>   online: If a room is available and you've submitted your credit card
>   details and agreed to the booking conditions on the booking form, the
>   reservation is then confirmed and a hotel voucher will be
>   automatically sent to your e-mail address. The hotel voucher is only
>   issued after we have verified and charged your credit card. The hotel
>   voucher AND credit card must be presented upon check-in at the hotel,
>   together with a valid form of photo ID.
>
> 2) Book Now Pay Later - Pay online: Book Now Pay Later is just that,
>   make a booking now, pay for it later. The booking will be instantly
>   confirmed. The booking conditions (cancellation policy) will determine
>   when you are billed. The actual charge date will be approximately 2-3
>   days prior to the hotel booking conditions becoming active. At that
>   time you will be charged the full amount. This option is only
>   available for Visa, MasterCard, AMEX and JCB. Please make sure you
>   select "Pay Later" when you input your credit card details.
>
> 3) Special Rates - Pay at the hotel: Agoda.com works in partnership
>   with other companies to ensure we offer the best rates. If you choose
>   to stay at a hotel where an agoda.com partner has provided the lowest
>   rate, we will confirm your reservation and issue a confirmation email.
>   In such cases we will not charge your card. You will be required to
>   pay the hotel directly upon check-out and the hotels own cancellation
>   policy will apply. The title of the rate section for these hotels is
>   'Special Rates' instead of 'Rate per room per night'.
>
> Please note: The hotel reserves the right to preauthorize/charge your
>   credit card prior to arrival. Timing and amount of charges will be in
>   line with the conditions of your booking.

So from that last paragraph, they might charge your card in advance, or it might be that you get charged when you arrive. Depends on the hotel.